# Rename multiple data files

Tags: hdfs

I am looking for solution to rename multiple data files in HDFS, I have let say 26000 data files /data/sample/*_file.json.zip with same name and removing .zip from the end of the file like /data/sample/*_file.json

what I want to do like ..

For one file i can do like

```
hdfs dfs -mv /data/sample/abc12300021b9_file.json.zip /data/sample/abc12300021b9_file.json
```

What I would like to do is to rename all 26000 data files like, I am getting following message

```
hdfs dfs -mv /data/sample/*_file.json.zip /data/sample/*_file.json
```

mv: `/data/sample/*_file.json': Too many matches

This code is doing what I want, BUT issue is that it is very slow, it is good for 100 or 200 data files, VERY SLOW when I am detailing with thousands of files.

```
#!/bin/bash

source_dir=/data/sample/

$(hdfs dfs -test -e  ${source_dir})

hdfs dfs -ls "${source_dir}/*.zip" | awk '{print $8}'  | while read FILE; do

FILENAME="$(basename "${FILE}")"
new_name=${FILENAME::-4}

hdfs dfs -mv "${source_dir}/${FILENAME}" "${source_dir}/${new_name}"

done
```

Answer (score 0):

Try for loop in bash

```
    for n in {0..26000} ; do
        long=$(printf %05d "$n")
        hdfs dfs -mv /data/sample/"$long"_file.json.zip /data/sample/"$long"_file.json
    done
```

Comment: How can I get list from this file name first? I am getting following message

Comment: + for n in '{0..26000}'
    ++ printf %05d 0 
    + long=00000 
    + hdfs dfs -mv /data/sample/00000_file.json.zip /data/sample/00000_file.json
mv: `/data/sample/00000_file.json.zip': No such file or directory

Comment: `abc12300021b9` do you have any sequence for names?

Comment: There is no sequence number in the file, number of files can be 3000 or 45899, so read file one by one from this location /data/sample/*_file.json.zip, and rename it /data/sample/*_file.json without .zip as an extension.

Comment: Please see I added a code which is doing job for me, and it is good for 100 or 200 data files, BUT VERY SLOW when I am dealing with thousands  data files. Can any one improve its performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pig script to do this.  It should look like this:

```
fs -mv /data/sample/abc12300021b9_file.json.zip /data/sample/abc12300021b9_file.json
fs -mv /data/sample/AAAAAAAA.json.zip /data/sample/AAAAAAAA.json
fs -mv /data/sample/AAAAAAAB.json.zip /data/sample/AAAAAAAB.json
....
```

Let's say the file was saved as `mv_26000_files`.  Then run:

```
pig -f mv_26000_files
```

It will be a lot faster since the authentication is only invoked once where using the HDFS CLI, you are invoking it for each time.

Note: Pig is available on all the major Hadoop distributions (CDH, HDP, MapR).

#### References

- [Beginners Guide to Apache Pig](https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/beginners-guide-to-apache-pig/)